# Eclipse can't find linked libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, mingw

I am working with the `windows.h` functions and everything works fine so far.
But when I try to use functions which require me to link external libraries something goes wrong.
In this case I am trying to use `CreateFont()`. I already know that I must link `libwinmm.a` and `libgdi32.a` and I've done that:
[See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6NRE.png)

But when I try to build the project i get following error messages:

```
g++ "-LD:\\Programme\\Eclipse\\lib" -o GameTest.exe "src\\choosemealmain.o" "src\\mealchooser.o" "-lD:\\Programme\\Eclipse\\lib\\libwinmm.a" "-lD:\\Programme\\Eclipse\\lib\\libgdi32.a" 

d:/programme/eclipse/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lD:\Programme\Eclipse\lib\libwinmm.a

d:/programme/eclipse/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lD:\Programme\Eclipse\lib\libgdi32.a
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I made sure to doublecheck whether the mentioned libraries are actually to be found in the mentioned path and they are.

I would be glad for any kind of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrongly using quotes with `-l` flag. The `-l` flag also automatically adds the `lib` prefix and the `.a` extension. Your command line should be:

```
g++ -LD:\Programme\Eclipse\lib -o GameTest.exe "src\choosemealmain.o" "src\mealchooser.o" -lwinmm -lgdi32
```